# Request form flask is empty in GET request

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, request, frontend

I'm trying to make a search form to get some data from my Api but the request form always return empty. I've read the other post with a similar problem but I didn't find the answer.

I just want to make an search from the main page and display de second page if the button of the form was pressed with some content.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():

    print(request.form)
    if 'btn_search' in request.form:
        search = request.args.get('search')
        print(search)
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/estacionesbykm/?ciudad='+search)
        render_template('estacion_por_ciudad.html', estaciones=json.loads(r.text), ciudad=search)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/estaciones/')
        return render_template('principal.html', estaciones=json.loads(r.text))
```

And the template of the homepage is also simple:

```
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <form method="GET">
        <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search city">
        <button name= "btn_search" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There is an special reason to why the form is returning me empty all the time?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the data from the form. As you are using a GET request, in flask you should acces them by this code

```
request.args['key']
```

You can use `reequest.form[]` when you are handling a POST request

Comment: Oh thanks it worked so args is for GET method and form to POST.